# Shell script: if: Expression syntax error

Tags: shell, if-statement, grep

I have a simple if loop which is working on one server but not on another. I could grep for the word in myscript.log log file.

```
#!/bin/ksh

./myscript.sh install $2 $3 $4
sleep 5
if grep -q SUCCESSFUL myscript.log
then
  echo "Install is good"
else
  echo "Error occured during Install"
fi
```

Output:

```
if: Expression Syntax.
```

Grep outside the script:

```
 mymachine:~>grep SUCCESSFUL myscript.log
 Install is SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: Are the line endings in the file nonnative?

Comment: To narrow the problem, try replacing the `grep` expression with `true` and see if that works.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` say?

Comment: @devnull : `echo $SHELL` output is 
`/usr/local/bin/tcsh`

Comment: @rkyser : I replaced `grep` with `true`. Still I am getting same error `if: Expression Syntax.`

Comment: @sravs448 This isn't valid syntax for csh/tcsh; hence the error.  Execute your script by saying `ksh filename` or `sh filename`.

Comment: Is the file executable? How are you actually running it?

Comment: @devnull : Its working if I run with `ksh` or `sh`

Answer (score 2):

The error:

> if: Expression Syntax

suggests that the shell you're using is not a variant of [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).

Another way to write the conditional statement would be:

```
grep -q SUCCESSFUL myscript.log && echo "Install is good" || echo "Error occured during Install"
```

(instead of the `if` ... `fi` loop.)

Comment: for simplicity purpose I just gave echo statements..but I have some complex code inside..so the above code without `if` may not work for me